# Coarea formula for fractional dimension

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

The [coarea formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarea_formula) states that any locally Lipschitz function (e.g. a $C^1$-function) $F:\mathbb{R}^N\to\mathbb{R}^n$ with $N\geq n$ satisfies
$$\int_A JF(x) \mathrm{d}\mathcal{H}^N = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \mathcal{H}^{N-n}(A\cap F^{-1}(y)) \mathrm{d}\mathcal{H}^n(y)$$
for all Lebesgue measurables $A\in\mathfrak{L}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ where $JF$ is the Jacobian $JF(x) := \det(DF(x)\cdot DF(x)^T)^{1/2}$. The change-of-variable formula is a special case of this and a combination of both shows the analogue formula for functions between Riemannian manifolds, the [smooth coarea formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_coarea_formula). Embedding this back into euclidean spaces this reads as
$$\int_A J_D F(x) \mathrm{d}\mathcal{H}^D = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \mathcal{H}^{D-n}(A\cap F^{-1}(y)) \mathrm{d}\mathcal{H}^n(y)$$
for integers $n\leq D\leq N$ and subsets of embedded $D$-manifolds $A$ and a modified Jacobian $J_D F$.

> My questions are simple: This last equation almost makes sense for all real numbers $D\in [n,N]$ and $\mathcal{H}^D$-measurable sets $A$. Is there an analogue of the Jacobian $J_D F$ that makes this fractional coarea formula true? If so, where can I find a proof?

(Similar questions have been asked, for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120462/co-area-formula-involving-non-integer-hausdorff-measure) (not answered) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107443/change-of-variable-within-an-integral-of-the-hausdorff-measure?rq=1) (answered, but not what I want to know) )